# python nosetest config file parse error

Tags: python, command-line, configuration, configuration-files, nosetests

my config file looks like this

```
# function class,dir, file match this regular expression are considered tests
[NOSE_TESTMATCH]
#by default this is-  (?:^|[\b_\./-])[Tt]est

# The file names after this block are ignored while testing
[NOSE_IGNORE_FILES]
test_case_1.py
# the regex that match the specified regex(if any) are excluded from tests
[NOSE_EXCLUDE]
#eg: test_s*

# the regex that match the specified regex(if any) are included from tests
[NOSE_INCLUDE]

#eg: test_s*
```

when I run nosetests with -c option I get this output

```
[kiran@my_redhat test]$ nosetests -w cases/ -s -c examples/nose_test.config
Usage: nosetests [options]

**nosetests: error: Error reading config file 'examples/nose_test.config': File contains parsing errors: examples/nose_test.config
        [line  7]: 'test_case_1.py\n'**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is really trivial.

basically documentation is not good.

its just one nosetests block and other options in subsequent lines.
eg

> [nosetests]
>
> ignore-files=abc.py

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
>[nosetests]
>ignore-files=<path of files>
>exclude=<path of files>
>include=<path of files>
```

would help

Comment: More details in your answer would be helpful